# Is this slash character in an Oracle PL/SQL script an error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm sorting out a series of SQL scripts for my company written in Oracle PL/SQL.  I came across an essential script with a strangely placed slash near the bottom.  It is checked into CVS this way.  Is this a pure syntax error or does it have some function I'm not aware of.  The slightly obfuscated script:

```
set serveroutput on size 2000;
--PL/SQL block to link ISSN in serial base on a company's ISSN text file

declare
    cursor ItemCursor is
        select issn is2 from web.obfuscated1 where issn is not null
            union
        select eissn is2 from web.obfuscated1 where eissn is not null;

    cursor ItemCursor1(aIS varchar2) is
        select obfuscated1_uid from web.obfuscated1 where group_num is null and issn in (
            select distinct issn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = aIS or eissn = aIS
                union
            select distinct eissn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = aIS or eissn = aIS
        )
            union
        select obfuscated1_uid from web.obfuscated1 where eissn in (
            select distinct issn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = aIS or eissn = aIS
                union
            select distinct eissn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = aIS or eissn = aIS
        );

    cursor ItemCursor2(aIS9 varchar2) is
        select obfuscated1_uid from web.obfuscated1 where issn in (
            select distinct issn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = aIS9 or eissn = aIS9
                union
            select distinct eissn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = aIS9 or eissn = aIS9
        ) and group_num is null;

    agroup      number(8);
    processCount    number(8);

    ------------------------------------------------------
    -- MAIN BLOCK -----------------------------------
    -------------------------------------------------
begin
    processCount := 0;

    agroup := null;
    for itemRec in ItemCursor loop
        agroup := null;
        begin
            select group_num into agroup from web.obfuscated1 where issn in (
                select distinct issn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = itemRec.is2 or eissn = itemRec.is2
                    union
                select distinct eissn from web.obfuscated1 where issn = itemRec.is2 or eissn = itemRec.is2
            ) and group_num is not null and issn is not null and eissn is not null and rownum <= 1;

        exception
            when no_data_found then
                agroup := null;
            when others then
                agroup := null;
        end;

        if agroup is not null then
            for itemRec2 in ItemCursor2(itemRec.is2) loop
                update web.obfuscated1 set group_num = agroup where obfuscated1_uid = itemRec2.obfuscated1_uid;
                commit;
            end loop;
        else
            processCount := processCount + 1;
            for itemRec1 in ItemCursor1(itemRec.is2) loop
                update web.obfuscated1 set group_num = processCount where obfuscated1_uid = itemRec1.obfuscated1_uid;
                commit;
            end loop;
            commit;
        end if;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Total record read: ' || processCount);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA' || sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(sqlerrm, 1, 255));
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA- Error during processing ' );
    end;
/
exit;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The slash has [a meaning](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12004.htm#SQPUG162):

> Executes the most recently executed
>   SQL command or PL/SQL block which is
>   stored in the SQL buffer. You can
>   enter a slash (/) at the command
>   prompt or at a line number prompt of a
>   multi-line command. The slash command
>   functions similarly to RUN, but does
>   not list the command.

Answer (score 7):

When using Oracle you "mix" three different grammars.

- SQL
- PL/SQL
- sqlplus (command line client)

sqlplus can execute/process SQL and PL/SQL statements by sending them onto DB server. While sqlplus commands are interpreted by sqlplus itself.

The semicolon ";" is not part of the SQL grammar and sqlplus recognizes it as the end of the SQL statement. While for PL/SQL it is part of the grammar and must must explicitly tell sqlplus that the statement ends here and should be executed by using slash.

The other sqlplus commands are "EXIT", "DEFINE" "VARIABLE" "PRINT" "SET <something>" (except SET ROLE).

On the other hand the Toad for example recognizes the end of the PL/SQL block when it sees an empty line.

Answer (score 5):

the / at the end is to tell the interpreter to execute the loaded script

basicaly you type stuff then type "/" and what you just typed will execute

Answer (score 3):

Both the slash and the "exit" make me suspect you are supposed to run this script from SQLPLUS. You may get an error if you try to submit it to Oracle in some other way. In that case, just get rid of both.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error. It executes the script.

It is useful when you concatenate various scripts together in one file and want each separate task to execute before the next one.

ie Create function
/ 
Create stored procedure that uses the function

Without the slash the stored procedure may get created with errors or may not get created.